# Dynamic variable substitution in vuejs

Tags: variables, vuejs2, substitution, dynamic-variables

I have the following dynamic var

{{ region }}

which could equal north, south, east or west.

I want to use it to pull in the variable from my data object

I tried

{{ #region.copy }}

Is this possible in vue

```
data: function() {
    return {
             north : {
                copy: "this is the north copy"
            },
            south : {
                copy: "this is the north copy"
            }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "pull the appropriate copy"?

Comment: Copy of what? Could you explain a little-bit? Maybe provide more code of what you are doing.

Comment: sorry - updated, just a string from my data object.

Answer (score 3):

You can put north, south, east and west in an object geo. In geo you can access your region by `geo[region].copy`. If `region === south` it will result in `geo.south.copy`

Edit: in computed variables you can also use `this[region].copy` instead of a geo wrap